# Utilizando case para igualar campos

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.5

Tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
---------------------------------------
|DT_Ven  | VLR_CONTA|DT_QUI  | VLR_QUI|
|--------------------------------------
|30/07/20|     84,00|NULL    |   84,00|
|03/08/20|    100,00|NULL    |  100,00|
|04/08/20|   1505,96|04/08/20| 1505,96|
|06/08/20|     10,00|06/08/20|   10,00|
|07/08/20|     50,00|07/08/20|   50,00|
|01/10/20|    350,00|01/10/20|  350,00|
|20/10/20|    200,00|20/10/20|  200,00|
---------------------------------------
```

Quero que o campo `DT_QUI` caso ele seja `Null` traga igual ao campo `DT_Ven` como esta abaixo.

```
---------------------------------------
|DT_Ven  | VLR_CONTA|DT_QUI  | VLR_QUI|
|--------------------------------------
|30/07/20|     84,00|30/07/20|   84,00|
|03/08/20|    100,00|03/08/20|  100,00|
|04/08/20|   1505,96|04/08/20| 1505,96|
---------------------------------------
```

já tentei o sql assim, mais da erro.

```
SELECT
    CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_VENC,
    CONTAS_PAGAR.VLR_CONTA, 
  CASE
    WHEN CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_QUITACAO IS NULL
      THEN CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_QUITACAO = CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_VENC 
    ELSE CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_QUITACAO
  END AS DT_QUITACAO,
    CONTAS_PAGAR.VLR_QUITACAO
FROM
    CONTAS_PAGAR
```

Comment: Você fez `THEN CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_QUITACAO = CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_VENC ` só deveria ser `THEN CONTAS_PAGAR.DT_VENC` e no final renomear com `AS` (alias ou apelido)

Comment: A sua estrutura de campos inicial não está igual as colunas do `SQL`. Na primeira tabela você não informou que existe o campo `SITUACAO`. Poderia editar a sua pergunta.

Comment: No lugar do CASE você pode utilizar a função COALESCE: `COALESCE(DT_QUIT, DT_VENC) AS DT_QUITACAO`, ela serve exatamente para isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-coalesce.html

```
SELECT CP.DT_VENC,
       CP.VLR_CONTA, 
       COALESCE(DT_QUIT, DT_VENC) AS DT_QUITACAO,
       CP.VLR_QUITACAO
  FROM CONTAS_PAGAR CP
```